# How to wrap two spans into one line with CSS

Tags: css, line, html

I want to wrap two `spans` in one line with CSS.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="width:60px;">
    <span id="span1" style="float:left; display:inline;"></span>
    <span id="span2" style="float:left; display:inline; "></span>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work.

How to do that?

**Edit:**

I want to use the "id", either use `div` or `span`, I just want them to be in one line.

When I just use `span` without style, the content are not in the same line. The second line will go down.

Comment: spans are `inline` elements anyway, you shouldn't have to do anything with them at all.

Comment: @garcon1986, Is it possible you have some style somewhere that's overriding the normal behaviour of the spans? At times like this, I try using the !important rule to see if I can force things to work - It helps determine the source of the issue. (as in display:inline !important;)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here is the working example:

```html
<div style="float:left;">
    <span style="display:inline; color: red;">First Span</span>
    <span style="display:inline; color: blue;">Second Span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've seen your link. Good resource. Thanks.

Comment: with or without that inline css I see no difference

Answer (score 8):

The float will mess things up.  Usually with a float to work you need a width with it as well.  It can't float them against each other because it doesn't know how much space each span will occupy in relation to the div.  Spans are inherently inline elements unless you define them otherwise, so they should just display that way without the float.

Answer (score 8):

```html
<div style="float:left;">
    <span style="display:contents; color: red;">First Span</span>
    <span style="display:contents; color: blue;">Second Span</span>
</div>
```

'display:contents' Makes the container disappear, making the child elements children of the element the next level up in the DOM which I believe is the right answer.

Another way which works on ie too is this:

```html
<div style="float:left; display:flex;">
    <span style="color: red;">First Span</span>
    <span style="color: blue;">Second Span</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the float left that is causing it to be on separate lines. Maybe try a `&nbsp;` (non breaking space) in between the spans.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases `display:inline` does not work, in such case try adding both spans in one parent span like below

```
<span>
  <span id="span1">Span 1</span>
  <span id="span2">Span 2</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use Table.
    
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Span 1 text</span></td>
            <td><span>Span 2 text</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Span 3 text</span></td>
            <td><span>Span 4 text</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Using a table as styling/layout element is discouraged, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html).

Answer (score 1):

Overflow maybe?

`<div style="width:60px; overflow:hidden;">`

Comment: @OP has been set `float:left` to the span. to make it to be in one line put overflow hidden to the div.

Answer (score 1):

The `float` and `display` styles are mutually exclusive, so there's no point using them together. Also `<span>` defaults to `display:inline;` so that's redundant anyway (unless you have some other style elsewhere setting them to something else?).